# dataimporthandler does not distribute documents on solr cloud

Tags: solr, solrcloud

we solr cloud with 4 shards and when we try to import the data using dataimporthandler, it does not distribute documents in all 4 shards.

Comment: Can you give more details? Is your data synced to some of the shards or none? Have you checked the logs for errors?

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding:

You need to define sharding yourself by using dataimport query something like this:

```
SELECT * from albums where id % 3 = 0
SELECT * from albums where id % 3 = 1
SELECT * from albums where id % 3 = 2
```

Reference: http://solr.pl/en/2010/12/27/data-import-handler-%E2%80%93-sharding-2/